# Fix <ul><li> menu from pushing <div> below

Tags: html, css

Another developer has made a menu in a nav tag that is like this:

_layout page

```html
<div>@Html.Partial("_menu")</div>
```

then in the _menu.cshtl page:

```html
<div>@Html.RenderMenu("mainMenu")</div>
```

In the C# code a bunch of ul and li nested elements are generated, which looks fine at first on the page.
But when you hover over one of the elements the nested elements drop down and the div right below that gets pushed down the page.  It's ugly.  How do I fix this?  Is there some CSS magic I can do to make it overwrite the div below rather than pushing it down?

Comment: You haven't given us any relevant code at all..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add position with a property value of **absolute** and a higher **z-index** to the element that shows on hover. You can control the position with **Top**, **Bottom**, **Left** and **Right** properties **values**.

**Example:**

```
ul {
position: absolute;
left: 0; /* Adjust as needed */
right: 0; /* Adjust as needed */
}
```

**Note:**  Make sure that the element that contains the element that shows on hover has a **position** property value of r**elative** to help contain the Ul(in this case). Otherwise, it will overlap.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to see without the code, but you can apply absolute positioning to overlapping element.( I have no clue which one is that as you didn't provide any code). So:

```
position: absolute
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make the position of the ul element relative.

```
ul{
    position: relative;
}
```